# How to send a message to a specific user using kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm actually trying to create an App where users can post Novels,etc they want to sell and i want that the post user should recieve something like a small notification when another user wants to buy the article. Can anyone help please...

Comment: You might need a server to do so. You can set up an API like `sendMessage(sender, receiver, text)` to save messages to your server and then get those messages with something like `getMessages(my_secret_key)`. Are you using a server to save the novels?

Comment: I'm using a database to store all the posted novels

Comment: well, you can create a database to save the actions sent from one user to another and then poll the database to see if there is something for a certain user and eventually show the notification.   Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology you can check some ways to do push notifications

Comment: Also check Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: okay. I will try